# Vertically centering content in a header?

Tags: html, css

How do I vertically center an img and an h1 in a div? Right now I have a png and an h1 in a header but the content is automatically in the top left. How do I put it in the middle and keep it responsive? Here's my HTML:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  max-height:680px;

}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="title">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <img id="arrows" src="images/arrows.png">
  <h3 id="sub-title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
</header>
```

edit: Sorry I should have mentioned that the header has a specific height. How do I put the text and image right in the middle of the header, both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is, because your code snippet shows everything in the middle. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Looks centered to me.

Comment: Do you want to horizontally center it or vertically in the same line?

Comment: it's horizontally centered. how do i vertically center it? like the title says...

Comment: They look vertically centered to me - http://jsfiddle.net/kztagk62/

Comment: I think he needs the header to be positioned in the middle of the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Comment: That's not what the question says "How do I vertically center an img and an h1 in a div? ". Voting to close as **unclear**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know two ways to align it vertically.

### First way: `using table`

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
         <h1 id="title">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
         <img id="arrows" src="images/arrows.png">
         <h3 id="sub-title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </header>
</div>
```

### Second way: `using relative position`

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
div.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
         <h1 id="title">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
         <img id="arrows" src="images/arrows.png">
         <h3 id="sub-title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them in a line and centered:

```
header{
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h3, img{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Centering it horizontally and vertically using Flexbox.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <img id="arrows" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <h3 id="sub-title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
  </header>
</div>
```